# Picker's for mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

Do we have UIAlert/Date picker kind of controls for cocoa mac desktop applications? (These controls are visually appealing)

Answer (score 3):

The analog of `UIAlertView` is an [`NSAlert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The analog of `UIDatePicker` is [`NSDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Their visual styles are different, of course.  They have existed for far longer than their UIKit counterparts.  I am unaware of any third-party implementation of `UIAlertView` or `UIDatePicker` for Mac OS that replicates the iOS look.